# Autoincrement primary key

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

In my application I have a model Client with int primary key Id. (model generated from database by metalsql)

```
var c = new Client{Name = "jonny"};
myDbContext.Client.InsertOnSubmit(c);
```

This code causes an error when I add the second client, because it turns out it Id field isn't being incremented. It just takes the default value of 0. Is there a smart way to make this autoincrement  work?

Comment: Can you not set the field as an identity so the database inserts the ID automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current table your column ID is not set to int **is identity** so you need to supply it.

```
var c = new Client{ID = 2,Name = "jonny"};
myDbContext.Client.InsertOnSubmit(c);
```

To solve this make sure your table ID column is Set to int **is identity** to make your code works

```
var c = new Client{Name = "jonny"};
myDbContext.Client.InsertOnSubmit(c);
```

See this link:

[Creating A Database In Microsoft Visual Studio 2010](http://www.programminghelp.com/web-development/asp-net/creating-a-database-in-microsoft-visual-studio-2010/)

Best Regards